# how to get cart total amount in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have deals products and normal products. I have a function for normal products which calculate grand toal is working fine but when I add deal product in the cart it did calculate the grand total but only normal prices not deals prices

get total of one product with quantity

```
    def get_total(self):
        price = self.product.price
        quantity = self.quantity
        total = price*quantity
        print(total)

        return total
```

function of get cart total

```
@property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitem = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum(item.get_total for item in orderitem)
        return total
```

i have two fields in databse

`price` and  `deal_price`

how i can calculate complete correct cart total?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute the grand total using deal_price.

**Example**

I'm not sure if this would work since i haven't seen the complete source but you need something like this

```
 def get_deal_total(self):
        price = self.product.deal_price
        quantity = self.quantity
        total = price*quantity
        print(total)

        return total

@property
    def get_cart_deal_total(self):
        orderitem = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum(item.get_deal_total for item in orderitem)
        return total
```

Comment: i did this and worked fine with deals products but the problem is when i add deals and normal products into the cart than showing error.

Comment: in the template i added this  ```{{order.get_cart_deal_total|floatformat:2}}``` insted of  ```{{order.get_cart_total|floatformat:2}}``` but throwing error when i added normal products into cart.

Comment: Well i can't help you without looking at the code? Have you hosted it on github yet?

Comment: what other code do you need to review for a solution? I will paste here. I have not uploaded it to Github. it's my final year project and evaluation is very near. please help me. or I should upload it to Github?

Comment: I'd need the model.py and views.py file for this specific app.

Comment: [views and models](https://github.com/zainalee/cart-total) Github link. please check out.